# Combining Select Case as Cell and Range in Worksheet_Change

Tags: vba, excel

I have a current worksheet that needs to have values from another worksheet when values from a certain range are changed. 
Also, I need to watch a certain cell value to execute another action, for this case, show a Msgbox.

I am using`Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` event but the whole code does not work when I specify `Select Case "$G$6"` and `Case "$G$24:$H$54"` and tried `Case Else` but did not work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Target.Address

        Case "$G$6"
            If InStr(1, Range("G6"), "PUMP") > 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Pump")
            ElseIf InStr(1, Range("G6"), "SKID") > 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Skid")
            End If

        Case "$G$24:$H$54"
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G24:H54")) Is Nothing Then
            If InStr(1, Range("G24"), "Calculate") > 0 And InStr(1, Range("G25"), "Outside Shelter") > 0 Then
                Cells(19, 8).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(159, 6).Value
                Cells(20, 9).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(163, 6).Value
                Cells(19, 11).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(160, 6).Value
                Cells(20, 10).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(164, 6).Value
            ElseIf InStr(1, Range("G24"), "Calculate") > 0 And InStr(1, Range("G25"), "Inside Shelter") > 0 Then
                Cells(19, 8).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(182, 6).Value
                Cells(20, 9).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(187, 6).Value
                Cells(19, 11).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(183, 6).Value
                Cells(20, 10).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(188, 6).Value
            End If
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: "Does not work" is unhelpful but my guess is that instead of "$G$24:$H$54" you need to check the intersect of Target and this range. As you have in the next line as it happens!

Comment: It's also hard to work out the logic of what you're doing in the second Case block. What happens if they change H30?

Comment: also `EnableEvents = True` and `ScreenUpdating = True` must be AFTER `End Select` otherwise they are part of case 2 and stay `False` in case 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case True

    Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("G6")) Is Nothing
        If InStr(1, Range("G6"), "PUMP") > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Pump")
        ElseIf InStr(1, Range("G6"), "SKID") > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Skid")
        End If

    Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("G24:H54")) Is Nothing
        If InStr(1, Range("G24"), "Calculate") > 0 _
                    And InStr(1, Range("G25"), "Outside Shelter") > 0 Then
            Cells(19, 8).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(159, 6).Value
            Cells(20, 9).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(163, 6).Value
            Cells(19, 11).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(160, 6).Value
            Cells(20, 10).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(164, 6).Value
        ElseIf InStr(1, Range("G24"), "Calculate") > 0 _
                    And InStr(1, Range("G25"), "Inside Shelter") > 0 Then
            Cells(19, 8).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(182, 6).Value
            Cells(20, 9).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(187, 6).Value
            Cells(19, 11).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(183, 6).Value
            Cells(20, 10).Value = Sheets("1").Cells(188, 6).Value
        End If

    End Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The idea is use `Select Case True`, which selects the `Not Intersect(Range1, Range2) Is Nothing`. And in general, it is better to work with the `Range("G6")` and compare it with `Target` than with `$G$6` and compare it with `Target.Address`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. I am new to VBA so these forums really help me understand it more. Again, thank you!